# osm2pgsql: does table planet_osm_roads contain any non-duplicate data?

Tags: openstreetmap, database, osm2pgsql

Although there is a [osm wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/schema#Tables_Created) that attempts to shed light on the different tables which are created within a postgres/postgis database there is something that is not quite made clear:

Is the data in table `planet_osm_roads` duplicate? (i.e. would it provide anything that could not also be retrieved *however indirectly* from the other tables `planet_osm_line`,`planet_osm_point`,`planet_osm_polygon` ?

Bonus: If as assumed this is duplicate stuff is there a way to prevent its creation in the first place (assuming it increases the costs both in time and memory and disk space)?

Comment: *osm2pgsql* is a *specific* purpose tool, written to setup the backend for the standardized Mapnik-based OSM rendering pipeline...and the `planet_osm_roads` table creation is hardcoded; it's a collection of `highway` tagged relations for low-zoom rendering, all 'duplicates'. either drop that table, check out the `--output multi` backend configuration options (you can freely setup the output table structure yourself, albeit manually), or look into other tools: *ogr2ogr*, *Imposum*, *Osmium*, *Osmosis*, *osm2po*, *osm2postgis*, *osm2postgres*, to name a few classics.

Comment: @ThingumaBoI thanks for your comment, which imho alraeady features most of the aspects I have asked, maybe it could become transformed to an answer as to accept it and more clearly mark it for others faceing a similar doubt?

Comment: yeah...I was too lazy to fill it with links and so on, will rephrase tonight to make it an answer.

Comment: that sounds great! Anyway thanks already for the hints!